# How do I restore the elementary OS Freya original sources list?

Tags: ppa, software-sources, sources

I have messed up the PPA and now I do not know how to revert the sources.list to its original form.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you don't have any elementary OS repositories launching *Software & Updates*  from Slingshot or terminal:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

If you have checked it, open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable 
sudo apt-get update
```

Try to check now for new updates with:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

That's all.

Comment: Glad to read it.  You're welcome